# Why is this simple program giving me seemingly incorrect output?

Tags: c, output

This is a simple program that I have an assignment to do.

> - Ask the user for a number, which you can assume will be 1 or larger
> - Counting by 3s, print the numbers from 1 up to the user number; for example up to 15 :    1, 4, 7, 10, 13
>     o   Print the numbers on one line
>     o   Also, find the sum of these numbers and print on next line,   35 in this case
> - In 1 program solve with a while loop and then again with a for loop

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int number;
int i = 1;
int sum = 0;


printf("Please enter a number greater than 1: ");
scanf("%d", &number);


while(i < number){
    printf("%d ", i);
    i+=3;

    sum = sum + i;
}

printf("\nThe sum of these numbers is: %d\n", sum);


    return 0;
}
```

This is example output :

> Please enter a number greater than 1: 15
>
> 1 4 7 10 13
>
> The sum of these numbers is: 50

I cannot for the life of me figure out why number (15) is being added to sum. The input 15 is being added to the sum of 1, 4, 7, 10, and 13. 
At what point in this program does i equal number?

I'm sorry if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Any help is appreciated. I want to understand what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You wrote the code; you should know what it does.

Comment: Debugger, step through, inspect values, follow execution.

Comment: please, put the `i += 3;` statement at the end of the loop body, as you are changing the processed number before doing the addition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` before adding it to the sum! If each number has been incremented by 3, then your total error will add up to 15 in this case.

Make sure you increment `i` only after you're done using it in each iteration:

```
while(i < number){
    printf("%d ", i);
    sum = sum + i;

    i+=3;
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! 
That is exactly it! I should have known that.
I had been staring at this for an hour trying to figure out what I did wrong. 
Thank you so much for this lesson learned!

Comment: Anytime! Another tip: If you had used a for-loop in this particular scenario, you might not have hit this issue: `for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=3) {...} // i increments at the end of the iteration`

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting 50 from

```
1 + 4 + 7 + 10 + 13 + number
```

Rather, it's

```
4 + 7 + 10 + 13 + 16
```

Same as

```
(1 + 3) + (4 + 3) + (7 + 3) + (10 + 3) + (13 + 3)"
```

or

```
(1 + 4 + 7 + 10 + 13 + (3+3+3+3+3)
```

The sum of the error just happens to equal `number`, but it didn't come from `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Just invert line computing the sum and the one adding 3 to i.